# How does licensing model work for Microsoft Office PerformancePoint Server 2007?

Tags: licensing, moss, performancepoint

I am confused about the licensing model for Microsoft PerformancePoint Server.

When I look at 
http://www.microsoft.com/business/performancepoint/howtobuy/default.aspx

I see a 20,000 USD Server License, plus a 200 USD CAL license. But the language is a bit vague about what this means-- is CAl required for any user looking at reports, or for report updaters/creators?

Thanks much,

d

-Peter

Comment: Not really a programming question, you'd get a better answer by asking a lawyer, not a programmer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [included with the Enterprise License](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/01/23/microsoft-business-intelligence-strategy-update-and-sharepoint.aspx) of MOSS 2007 now.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not a lawyer or anything, but this license term looks like something that Microsoft can't actually enforce.  Sometimes they put terms in licenses that are legally baseless(i.e. they couldn't sue you and win) and just assume you'll follow the license because you're afraid.

Comment: I don't understand these downvotes.  This is actually true.  Part of the MS strategy is to make you afraid to violate the license so they can put terms in there that are not legally enforceable.